The Continuous Dual of Weak Topologies
Let $X$ be Banach, $F\subseteq X^*.$ Then define $\tilde{F}=(X,σ(X,F))^*,$ the collection of functionals continuous w.r.t. $σ(X,F).$ Equivalently, we could define $\tilde{F}$ to be the maximal subset of $X^*$ s.t. $σ(Χ,\tilde{F})=σ(X,F).$ Intuitively, $\tilde{F}$ should be some kind of closure of the span of $F.$ Is there some known topology on $X^*$ which makes $\tilde{F}=\overline{\mathrm{span}}(F)$ for every $F?$ I believe the coarsest topology which makes this hold is well defined, though doesn’t lend much help towards the computation of $\tilde{F}.$
I suppose I should clarify my motive: I want to upper bound $\tilde{F},$ in particular, find which $F$ satisfy $\tilde{F}\subset X^*.$
Also, we take the convention that $σ(X,\emptyset)$ is the trivial topology, so that we need not stipulate $F$ nonempty.

Just to confirm, are you looking for the coarsest topology $\tau$ on $X^{}$ which satisfies $(X, \sigma (X, F))^{} = \overline{{\rm span}}^{\tau}(F)$ for every nonempty $F \subseteq X^{*}$?

@DeanMiller It need not be the coarsest, I’m hoping there exists some known topology on $X^*$ which makes the equalities hold.

No topology is needed - it is quite a standard fact that $\tilde{F}$ is just $\text{span}(F)$. See, for example, here.

Wow, that’s embarrassing. I missed that paragraph. I figured situations could arise where nontrivial functions could be made continuous.
